# Loose focus on react input box after one character input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

When I enter a character in the input box

1. The state updates with the new character
2. Then I loose focus on the input box

so I can only modify the box 1 keypress at at time

The input box is nested in 4 other components which includes 1 higher Order component (see below)

Page component 
header(Modify)   
InputForm

When I move the form code to the Page component it works.

How I keep the components separate (and reusable) and have the functionlity I need?

The form code is below

```
 <input
          key={props.id}
          id={props.id}
          type='text'
          value={props.currentObject.name}
          onChange={(event) => {
            userFunctions.modifyItem(
              editorState,
              props.currentObject,
              stateModifier,
              event,
              'name'
            );
          }}
        />
```

The full code for the entiure component is here

```
mport React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const InputForm = (props) => {
  //prepare props
  console.log('currentObject', props.currentObject);
  const { editorState, stateModifier, userFunctions } = props.editorEssentials;

  // const urlFormVisible = props.urlFormVisible;

  //Styles
  const componentStyle = 'container-flex-column';

  // console.log('MOdify: currentState', editorState);
  // console.log('MOdify: targetObject', currentObject);
  // console.log('MOdify: stateModifier', stateModifier);
  console.log('currentObject.name', props.currentObject.name);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form
        className={componentStyle}
        // onSubmit={(event) =>
        //   userFunctions.submitItem(editorState, currentObject, stateModifier, event)
        // }
      >
        <input
          key={props.id}
          id={props.id}
          type='text'
          value={props.currentObject.name}
          onChange={(event) => {
            userFunctions.modifyItem(
              editorState,
              props.currentObject,
              stateModifier,
              event,
              'name'
            );
          }}
        />
        {props.urlFormVisible && (
          <input
            type='url'
            value={props.currentObject.url}
            onChange={(event) =>
              userFunctions.modifyItem(
                editorState,
                props.currentObject,
                stateModifier,
                event,
                'url'
              )
            }
          />
        )}
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default InputForm;
```

The function operates on the state and is bound in the master component

WHAT I HAVE TRIED
There are some similar posts on stack overflow but they do not seem to answer my problem.

1. Changed the Key value in the input (although my original version of this had a no ket defined)
2. Double checked that the modifyItem function is bound correctly - it looks like it is and I guess if it wasn't the state would not update at all
3. Tried simplifing code to reduce the number of functions needed to run

MOVING THE COMPONENT THE CODE HAS MADE

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but the Higher order component was the problem

when I changed the config from

Page component
header(Modify)
InputForm

to
Page component
header
Modify
InputForm
/header

It worked

Any ideas why I had this problem?